# What is the #target_type value used by the EntityAutocomplete class?

Tags: 8, entities

What is the #target_type value accepted by [`EntityAutocomplete`](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/core%21lib%21Drupal%21Core%21Entity%21Element%21EntityAutocomplete.php/class/EntityAutocomplete/8.2.x)?

The documentation for [`EntityAutocomplete::processEntityAutocomplete()`](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/core!lib!Drupal!Core!Entity!Element!EntityAutocomplete.php/function/EntityAutocomplete%3A%3AprocessEntityAutocomplete/8.2.x) says it's the ID of the target entity type.

How can I get a list of possible IDs I could use?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The ID accepted from `EntityAutocomplete` is an entity type identifier for an entity defined from Drupal core, or third-party, modules.

You don't normally need to have a list of all the possible entity type IDs, since you normally know which entity your code is going to autocomplete, but the list can be easily obtained using the following code.

```php
print_r(array_keys(\Drupal::entityTypeManager()->getDefinitions()));
```

I ran `drush ev "print_r(array_keys(\\Drupal::entityTypeManager()->getDefinitions()));"` on my test site, and I got the following.

```
[0] => block
[1] => block_content
[2] => block_content_type
[3] => comment
[4] => comment_type
[5] => editor
[6] => field_config
[7] => field_storage_config
[8] => file
[9] => filter_format
[10] => image_style
[11] => configurable_language
[12] => language_content_settings
[13] => mollom_form
[14] => node
[15] => node_type
[16] => rdf_mapping
[17] => responsive_image_style
[18] => search_page
[19] => shortcut
[20] => shortcut_set
[21] => action
[22] => menu
[23] => taxonomy_term
[24] => taxonomy_vocabulary
[25] => tour
[26] => user_role
[27] => user
[28] => view
[29] => menu_link_content
[30] => date_format
[31] => entity_form_display
[32] => entity_form_mode
[33] => entity_view_display
[34] => entity_view_mode
[35] => base_field_override
```